# How do I use an if statement when working with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want it to be where if the course they enter is not one from the courses_avalible list to print an error, else assign the course they entered from the list.

here is my code:

```
name = input("Whats your name?: ")
age = int(input("Whats your age?: "))

courses_avalible = ["Math", "Business", "Finance", "Code"]

print("Hello, " + name + ". Your avalible courses to enrolll in are: " + str(courses_avalible))

course = input("What course would you like to enroll in? ")

if course != courses_avalible:
    print("Course not avalible, please choose a course from the list above.")
else:
    assign = name + " has been enrolled in " + course
    print(assign)
```

Comment: You can use `if course not in courses_available`

Comment: @Ronan , actually `try/expects` are more preferable

Comment: @theX Thanks, good to know.

Comment: Get in the habit of posting your code directly, rather than an image of it. It makes it easier for the community to help and edit as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute code when a value is not found in the list, you would use:

```
if value not in list:
```

For your specific example, you could use:

```
if course not in courses_available:
    print("Course not available, please choose a course from the list above.")
else:
    #code to execute when the input is in the list
```

Comment: Your answer gave me a clear idea on how it is usued thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `not in` operator for lists i.e.:

```
if course not in courses_avalible:
    print(...)
else:
    assign = ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped solve my problem! +1

Answer (score 1):

Python is pretty neat and lets you do the following:

```
if course not in courses_available:
    # code
```

It just checks if the `course` was in `courses_avalible`.

Comment: `try/expects` are the preferred way to catch an error

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just to use the in syntax Python provides which checks if the value is in the array like so:

```
if course not in courses_avalible:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: It has to be indented. Also, use `#` for comments in python

Comment: yeah just realised, been working with javascript all day